# countplot and pieplot inverting labels colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I´m plotting a countplot and a pieplot but "male" and "female" are tagged in opposite colors in each of them

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(20,5))
sns.countplot(x="sex",data=insurance_ds) #plotting histogram
plt.title("Male/Female Frequency",fontsize=25)
plt.xlabel("Sex",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Frequency",fontsize=20)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.yticks(rotation=45)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(5,5))
insurance_ds["sex"].value_counts().plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True,textprops={'fontsize': 10}) 
plt.title("Male/Female Frequency",fontsize=25)
```

[image: Plots]

Comment: You could use the `order=` parameter:  `sns.countplot(...., order=['male', 'female'])`. Alternatively, you could use pandas plotting for both plots: `insurance_ds["sex"].value_counts().plot.bar(...)` instead of seaborn's count plot.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your column as a category, it should work too:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

insurance_ds = pd.DataFrame({'sex':np.random.choice(['male','female'],1000)})
insurance_ds['sex'] = pd.Categorical(insurance_ds['sex'],categories=['male','female'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,5))
sns.countplot(x="sex",data=insurance_ds,ax=ax[0]) 
insurance_ds["sex"].value_counts().plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True,textprops={'fontsize': 10},ax=ax[1])
```

[image]